# Dynamic JOIN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join

i have table:

```
Tbl1
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
| 1  |  11  | 
| 1  |  22  | 
| 2  |  *   |
+----+------+


Tbl2
+----+------+------+
| id | type | name |
+----+------+------+
| 1  |  11  | AAA  |
| 1  |  22  | BBB  |
| 2  |  11  | CCC  |
| 2  |  22  | DDD  |
+----+------+------+
```

I want to JOIN ON id AND type. But if type = '*' i want get all type. 
how to join Tbl1 and Tbl2 to achieve this result?

Something like:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Tbl2 a 
INNER JOIN Tbl1 b ON a.id = b.id  
AND a.type = b.type ?? (i want use case statement to achieve this result)

result
+----+------+------+
| id | type | name |
+----+------+------+
| 1  |  11  | AAA  |
| 1  |  22  | BBB  |
| 2  |  11  | CCC  |
| 2  |  22  | DDD  |
+----+------+------+
```

Comment: try `... a.type = case when a.type = '*' then '*' else b.type end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the condition in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Tbl2 a INNER JOIN
     Tbl1 b
     ON a.id = b.id AND
        (a.type = b.type OR a.type = '*' OR b.type = '*');
```

It is unclear whether you intend for the wildcard to apply to both tables or just one.  If one, then remove the condition on `a.type = '*'`.